# Can't install TFS plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, tfs

I try to install TFS plugin in Eclipse on Mac.

I go through the first steps of installation wizard successfully, but after hitting "Finish" I get the following error :

```
Installing Software has encoutered a problem. An error occured while installing the items
```

Plugin name is Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010. Can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4240).

Does anybody encountered the same problem / found a workaround?

Some more informations :

- I am using latest version of Eclipse
  Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
  Build id: 20140612-0600
- JDK is 7.1
- "Details" are :

  ```
  An error occurred while installing the items
  session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard,
  phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, 
  operand=null --> [R]com.microsoft.tfs.checkinpolicies 10.0.0.201003261741, action=).
  Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.microsoft.tfs.checkinpolicies 10.0.0.201003261741.
  ```

Comment: what version of tfs are you using (2010, 12, 13?). There's newer versions of that plugin available. that 10.0 plugin won't play nicely with tfs12->
if someone's specified some of the newer checkin policies it won't work.

Comment: Great! Indeed, as you said, there is a newer version of the plugin : Microsoft Team Explorer Everywhere 2013. I tried it, and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

what version of tfs are you using (2010, 12, 13?). There's newer versions of that plugin available. that 10.0 plugin won't play nicely with tfs12-> if someone's specified some of the newer checkin policies it won't work.